# Unable to present the data in jqgrid ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid-asp.net

I am trying to send the data(json object) from a controller to the view and display the data in a jqgrid, but I am unable to bind the data with the jqgrid. The data is being printed in the browser in JSON format. I am not able to figure out where the code went wrong. [here is the output what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHiBG.png)

*CONTROLLER*

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Prism.Models;
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;


    namespace Prism.Controllers
    {
        public class SakilaController : Controller
        {
            // GET: Sakila
            public JsonResult Index()
            {
                List<ActorModel> actormodel = new List<ActorModel>();
                using (var context = new sakilaEntities())  
                {

                    List<actor> b = context.actors.ToList();
                    actormodel.Add(new ActorModel()
                    {id = 1,
                     f_name = "MS",
                     l_name = "Vivek",
                     last_update = DateTime.Now});
                 }
        return Json(actormodel.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

       }
     }
   }
```

*Index.cshtml*

```html
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/MyGrid.js"></script>


 test
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: 'Index/Sakila',
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        colNames: ['actor_id', 'f_name', 'l_name'],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 20 },
        { name: 'f_name', index: 'f_name', width: 150 },
        { name: 'l_name', index: 'l_name', width: 150 }
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        mtype: "POST",
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#pager',
        loadonce: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        autoencode: true,
        caption: "Company approval"
    });
    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
});

</script>
  
    
 <table id="grid" ></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

*Layout*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
      <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
  </div>

  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try alter your jqGrid url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="Index", controller="Sakila"})'

Comment: . Thanks for your response. I already tried but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I figured out is your browser is hitting 'shakila/index' which is method a that returning a JsonResult. So it is true you should be getting a JSON object via Browser.

In your Jqgrid code you are using url as'Index/Sakila' which is a method that you have not mention in this question.(I dont know it is exist or not)

Based on above I would like to suggest you, To use proper urls for each request.
The browser url should hit to a conroller method which is returning a view in order to view your page in the browser and Jqgrid should call the correct JsonResult method to populate properly.(as per question 'shakila/index')

Code sample

JS

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: 'Sakila/GetData',
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        colNames: ['actor_id', 'f_name', 'l_name'],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 20 },
        { name: 'f_name', index: 'f_name', width: 150 },
        { name: 'l_name', index: 'l_name', width: 150 }
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        mtype: "POST",
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#pager',
        loadonce: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        autoencode: true,
        caption: "Company approval"
    });
    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
```

C#

```
 public class SakilaController : Controller
        {

            public JsonResult Index()
            {
              return view();
            }
            public JsonResult GetData()
            {
                List<ActorModel> actormodel = new List<ActorModel>();
                using (var context = new sakilaEntities())  
                {

                    List<actor> b = context.actors.ToList();
                    actormodel.Add(new ActorModel()
                    {id = 1,
                     f_name = "MS",
                     l_name = "Vivek",
                     last_update = DateTime.Now});
                 }
        return Json(actormodel.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

       }
     }
```

Browser is calling **Sakila/Index** and Jqgrid is calling **Sakila/GetData**
Please note that MVC url pattern is working as ControllerName/MethodName

Comment: got it. Thank you. Previously I was returning the Json object and not the Index view.